# What could be causing "[WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine"?

Tags: python, sockets

I am attempting socket programming with Python, and am attempting to send a series of messages between different nodes and ports on my own host machine. Here is my code:

```
import socket
import random #need this for generating our messages, so our passengers

#Server 1 - Our airport ANC
anc_ip = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' #amended for privacy
anc_port = 9000 

#server 2, our SEA airport

sea_ip = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
sea_port = 9001

address = {
    "ANC": anc_ip,
    "SEA": sea_ip
    }

port = {
    "ANC": anc_port,
    "SEA": sea_port
    }
#create our sockets for our servers

server_socket_1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket_2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#bind each server socket to its respective IP address and port
server_socket_1.bind((anc_ip, anc_port))
server_socket_2.bind((sea_ip, sea_port))

#set up listening range/queue 
server_socket_1.listen(7)
server_socket_2.listen(7)

#test our servers' connections
def test_server_connection(server_name, address, port):
    s = socket.socket()
    try:
        s.connect((address, port))
        print(f"Connection to {server_name} at {address}:{port} is successful.")
        print(f"{server_name} airport is ready to route and receive passengers.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to connect to {server_name} at {address}:{port}. Exception: {str(e)}")
    finally:
        s.close()

servers = ["ANC", "SEA"]

for server_name in servers:
        test_server_connection(server_name, address[server_name], port[server_name])


#print(f"ANC is ready to route and receive passengers")
#print(f"SEA is ready to route and receive passengers")

#client nodes
client_socket_FAI_to_ANC = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) #fairbanks route 1
client_socket_FAI_to_SEA = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) #fairbanks route 2
client_socket_BRW = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) #barrow minor hub  
client_socket_OTZ = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) #random place hub

#connect our fairbanks hub to anc and sea, as it can route to sea directly, or stop in anc first
client_socket_FAI_to_ANC.connect((anc_ip, anc_port))
client_socket_FAI_to_SEA.connect((sea_ip, sea_port))

#connect brw and otz to anc only
client_socket_BRW.connect((anc_ip, anc_port))
client_socket_OTZ.connect((anc_ip, anc_port))

#accept incoming connections
client_socket_FAI_to_ANC, _ = server_socket_1.accept()
client_socket_FAI_to_SEA, _ = server_socket_2.accept()
client_socket_BRW, _ = server_socket_1.accept()
client_socket_OTZ, _ = server_socket_1.accept()


#create receive sockets for each client
# Data for each client
data_FAI_to_ANC = "Data for FAI to ANC"
data_FAI_to_SEA = "Data for FAI to SEA"
data_BRW = "Data for BRW"
data_OTZ = "Data for OTZ"

# Encode and send data for each client
data_FAI_to_ANC_encoded = data_FAI_to_ANC.encode('utf-8')
data_FAI_to_SEA_encoded = data_FAI_to_SEA.encode('utf-8')
data_BRW_encoded = data_BRW.encode('utf-8')
data_OTZ_encoded = data_OTZ.encode('utf-8')

client_socket_FAI_to_ANC.send(data_FAI_to_ANC_encoded)
client_socket_FAI_to_SEA.send(data_FAI_to_SEA_encoded)
client_socket_BRW.send(data_BRW_encoded)
client_socket_OTZ.send(data_OTZ_encoded)

# Receive data for each client
received_data_FAI_to_ANC = client_socket_FAI_to_ANC.recv(1024) #Exception is thrown here
received_data_FAI_to_SEA = client_socket_FAI_to_SEA.recv(1024)
received_data_BRW = client_socket_BRW.recv(1024)
received_data_OTZ = client_socket_OTZ.recv(1024)
```

I attempted going offline, messing around with my firewall advanced settings on those ports, but that didn't seem to have any affect on the issue. Not sure if there's a general fix or if it's something specific to what be doing wrong in my code.

Comment: Not a Python problem, unfortunately -- I'd look into what endpoint security tooling is installed, and generally chat with IT.

Comment: Are you attempting to create a server socket on another machine?  That's not how it works.  When you call `bind`, you must always supply an IP address for your computer.  If you want to receive on `anc_ip`, then you must run the script on that computer.  Try using `'127.0.0.1'` for both IP addresses and it should be better.

Comment: And I hope this is all just for playing around, because that's not how you write socket code.  You should have a loop for each server that does an `accept` and then handles the traffic for that connection.

Comment: As it is, your first `connect` call is going to hang until it gets an `accept`, which it will never get to.  This needs to be asynchronous.

Comment: @TimRoberts No, I'm only using ports on my own machine, just simulating a network on my own host computer. I omitted the server socket IP's, but they're both identical to my own host computer. And yes this is just for a class, not for work or anything. I'm newish to python, and newer to socket programming, so I'm aware it's rough shod work but I'm trying with it. I'll try your recommendations, thanks.

Comment: You may be able to use threading or asyncio to do this, but you can't do it linearly like that.  The `accept` call has to be running at the same time as the `connect`.